# Why won't my snap.svg drag elements work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, snap.svg

I've built an interactive web app where I'm using snap.svg to create a perspective grid and accompanying UI elements.

See this codepen of a stripped down version of the web app:

`codepen URL`
https://codepen.io/reubenlara/pen/dxoJWK?editors=0010

I'm using snap.svg for dragging the UI circle elements and d3 for zooming/panning the grid (couldn't find a stable snap.svg zoom/pan solution). Works perfectly on desktop, but on mobile (iPad), my snap.svg circle elements won't respond to touch events. They do drag around fine without the d3 zoom implementation, but as soon as d3 zoom is applied to the grid, they stop responding to touch. Any reason why?

I'm hoping to get the circle UI elements to drag around using touch events just like they do with the mouse on the desktop. Keep in mind that they do respond to touch when d3 zoom is removed from the equation. Thanks!